# Microsoft Office SmartArt - Continue on new line

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

How can I make this series continue on a new line when it become to small to see properly?

This is the document I currently have:

[image: Long SmartArt on one line]

As you can see it is particually hard to read, so I would like a way to make it take up the page space effectively

Comment: Why not just insert another SmartArt of the same layout below the current one?

Comment: I split very long process to three lines this way and manually appended an arrow at the end of each section. I have copied the arrow when temporarily breaking the group like Taylor proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just break the SmartArt Graphic, and then re-size the layout as you see fit. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> twice to break the SmartArt Graphic.

See tip #2 in the [**PowerPoint Tricks: Four Things You Didn't Know You Could Do In PowerPoint**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05OW0Ce8rT8) YouTube Tutorial.